# Divisibility by 101; a problem with induction

Tags: induction, divisibility

I was trying to show that $10^{2n}+(-1)^{n+1}$ is  divisible by $101$. Would anyone help me with  the induction step please?

Comment: Is this question trivial?

Comment: Depends on what you're familiar with.  That's why it's useful to provide context (e.g., your mathematics background, what you're currently studying, the tools you have at your disposal and how you've tried to use them).  What's trivial for someone else may not be trivial for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** You should try writing out the sequence.  For instance, for $n = 1$, we have $101$; for $n = 2$, we have $9999$; and so on.  Then try dividing the second term by the first term, the third term by the second term, the fourth term by the third term.  You should see a pattern that will help you construct the induction step.  (It will be convenient to break it down by even and odd $n$, as hinted at by the $(-1)^{n+1}$.)

Answer (score 1):

Taking module 101, $10^{2n}= 100^n\equiv (-1)^n(\mathrm{mod}101)$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$10^{2(n+1)}+(-1)^{(n+1)+1}=100\cdot10^{2n}-(-1)^{n+1}=101\cdot10^{2n}-\underbrace{(10^{2n}+(-1)^{n+1})}_{\text{multiple of }101}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard fact that $a-b \mid a^n-b^n$ as follows :
$$101=100-(-1)\mid 100^n-(-1)^n=10^{2n}+(-1)^{n+1}$$

Comment: Though I have voted to close the question, this is a very nice answer, +1

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following steps of mathematical induction,

1. Setting $n=1$ in the given number $10^{2n}+(-1)^{n+1}$ gives $$10^{2\cdot 1}+(-1)^{1+1}=101$$ above number is divisible by $101$ for $n=1$
2. assume that $10^{2n}+(-1)^{n+1}$ is divisible by $101$ for $n=k$ then $$10^{2k}+(-1)^{k+1}=101m$$
   or $$10^{2k}=101m-(-1)^{k+1}\tag 1$$
   where, $m$ is some integer
3. setting $n=k+1$, $$10^{2(k+1)}+(-1)^{k+1+1}$$
   $$=100\cdot 10^{2k}-(-1)^{k+1}$$
   setting the value of $10^{2k}$ from (1), 
   $$=100(101m-(-1)^{k+1})-(-1)^{k+1}$$
   $$=101(100m)-101(-1)^{k+1}$$
   $$=101(100m-(-1)^{k+1})$$

since, $(100m-(-1)^{k+1})$ is an integer hence the number $101(100m-(-1)^{k+1})$ is divisible by $101$

thus $10^{2n}+(-1)^{n+1}$ is divisible by $101$ for $n=k+1$

hence, $10^{2n}+(-1)^{n+1}$ is divisible by $101$ for all integers $n\ge 1$